# SAP UI5/FioriElements: this.getview is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

Although many questions exist on the same topic, I could not resolve​ this using the given solutions.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Vsb.png)

[Snippet from the manifest.json to trigger the same]((https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb7g6.png)

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q829f.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rvta.png)

How can I resolve this issue?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` is placed in the wrong context or there is no object available while you should have an object for the controller.

Most probably you can reach `Source` through `oEvent` (`oEvent.getSource()`), which will point out to the controller and then you could call `getView()`:

```
oEvent.getSource().getView()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it, but it cannot find getSource()